# JSF - Problemas no deploy com Wildfly e Tomcat9 (web.xml e faces-config)

Tags: java, jsf, maven, tomcat, wildfly

Olá, pessoal! Bom dia.

To com um problemão que p/ mim é bizarro. Tenho um projetinho aqui bem simples, mas que não to conseguindo subir. Quando eu rodo ele a partir do projeto inteiro (botão direito - Run As - Run on Server), dão erros como se as configurações estivessem erradas. Aí que vem o que eu não estou entendendo.

**Meu web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>javax.servlet.Filter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

**Meu faces-config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_3.xsd"
    version="2.3">
    <lifecycle>
        <phase-listener>br.com.forumbrabo.util.Listener</phase-listener>
    </lifecycle>
</faces-config>
```

Até aqui, parece tudo ok. Porém acesso o .war do meu projeto nos diretórios do Tomcat9 ou do Wildfly 21, eles estão diferentes. No caso do web.xml, está sem as tag `<welcome-list>` e, consequentemente, `<welcome-file>`, e é adicionado a tag `<display-name>`. Já no caso do faces-config, está sem `<lifecycle>` e, consequentemente, sem o `<phase-listener>`.

O resultado é que quando tento rodar pelo wildfly, dá Forbidden, me obrigando a completar a URL com "/login.xhtml", ou rodando o projeto a partir do arquivo xhtml. Quando tento rodar no tomcat é ainda pior, porque o projeto não roda de jeito nenhum. Logo quando inicio o tomcat, me aparece isso no console do Eclipse:

```
GRAVE: Critical error during deployment: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.faces.application.Application.addSearchKeywordResolver(Ljavax/faces/component/search/SearchKeywordResolver;)V
    at org.primefaces.util.Jsf23Helper.addSearchKeywordResolvers(Jsf23Helper.java:38)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener.processEvent(PostConstructApplicationEventListener.java:56)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2169)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2142)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.publishPostConfigEvent(ConfigManager.java:704)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4714)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5177)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)

mar 30, 2021 9:12:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Exceção ao enviar evento de contexto iniciado para instância listener da classe [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.faces.application.Application.addSearchKeywordResolver(Ljavax/faces/component/search/SearchKeywordResolver;)V
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4714)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5177)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.faces.application.Application.addSearchKeywordResolver(Ljavax/faces/component/search/SearchKeywordResolver;)V
    at org.primefaces.util.Jsf23Helper.addSearchKeywordResolvers(Jsf23Helper.java:38)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener.processEvent(PostConstructApplicationEventListener.java:56)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2169)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2142)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.publishPostConfigEvent(ConfigManager.java:704)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:270)
    ... 30 more
```

Adicional: **Meu pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>projforum</groupId>
    <artifactId>projforum</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>projforum</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>
            <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.heroku</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>9.0.30.0</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```

IDE: Eclipse
JSF 2.2
Maven
Tomcat9/Wildfly 21
JDK 1.8

Valew, pessoal! o/

Edit: Recriei o projeto e os arquivos estão indo normal p/as pastas dos servidores, mas o tomcat ainda está soltando esse erro.
Não entendo o porquê.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi! Foi só criar um filter com o seguinte código:

```
package br.com.forumbrabo.util;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpFilter;

public class MyCustomFilter extends HttpFilter {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyCustomFilter.class.getName());

    public MyCustomFilter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.doFilter(req, res, chain);
        log.info("filter Request");
    }

}
```

Depois substituí o Filter padrão no web.xml:

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>myCustomFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>br.com.forumbrabo.util.MyCustomFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
```

Só não sei dizer até aonde é bom substituir o filter padrão por esse, se é melhor deixar ele lá também... Vou fazendo uns testes e qualquer coisa volto aqui com o resultado. Valew! o/